# I tried to remove drop shadow from QToolTip

Tags: qt

I want to modify the style of all the tool tip windows in my application.
Please help to make it

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] would make it more likely that someone tries to write an answer for you. It's much easier to do a small change to an existing code, than to write an entire example application for you. You can probably make a single .cpp file which just sets a tooltip to a standard Qt widget and sets its style sheet with your best attempt.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's only a dirty hack for this: Set the background as transparent and duplicate the background then. E.g.

```
ToolTip{
  background: Rectangle{id: bg; color: Qt.rgba(0,0,0,0); }
}

Rectangle{
  id: realBg
  x: bg.x
  y: bg.y
  width: bg.width
  height: bg.height
  color: Qt.rgba(1,1,1,1)
}
```

I know it's ugly, but it works.. I used this technique to make custom shadows using a Canvas element instead of a Rectangle as BG